# Export Points of Interest data from Xcode Instruments

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

It's great to view the signpost data in instruments like:

[image]

But I'd like to create my own reporting tool also. Is there a way I can export just the signpost data from Points of Interest in Instruments? There doesn't seem to even be a way to copy/paste all - let alone export.